# What is swift equivalent for objective c initialization allocWithZone used for UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was trying to find answer for translating my code from Objective c to Swift, but explanations that i found didn't resolve my problem. Here is my Objective C code:

```
@implementation ComponentViewController  //  inherits UIViewController

@synthesize layout    // which is NSDictionary

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
 ComponentViewController *componentViewController = [[ComponentViewController allocWithZone:zone] init];
 [componentViewController setLayout:self.layout];
 return componentViewController;
}
```

Since i am mistaking in Swift translation because allocWithZone is deprecated, i can't get this method correctly, and because of that i can't get right data for my dictionary LAYOUT. Here is what i've done in Swift:

```
class ComponentViewController: TableViewController {

var layout = [NSObject:AnyObject]()

func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
    let componentViewController = UIViewController() as! ComponentViewController
    componentViewController.layout = self.layout
    return componentViewController as AnyObject
}

}
```

Please, help me with this, i tried with something like self.dynamicType, and other code that i found googling, but can't figure this out.

Comment: so, UIViewController() will initialize new instance of UIViewController not ComponentViewController. Replace UIViewController() with ComponentViewController(). In swift you don't need to call alloc, swift handles this for you. Check this for more info:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, but there is a little extra problem if i do that. I need to initialize ComponentViewController with coder, and at this moment Swift doesn't let me use empty parentheses for initialization of ComponentViewController, since this controller is 3-rd subclass from UIViewController.  Can i declare property -> var myCoder = NSCoder(), and give it value in initWithCoder method, from its super coder, and then use that property, myCoder, as requested initializator for ComponentViewController in other words like this:  ComponentViewController(myCoder)

Comment: In the ObjC code, you aren't using `initWithCoder:`.  Why would the Swift code need to use it?